# Java netty get POST Request Content

Tags: java, netty

i am using netty 4.1 embeded in Java and trying to retrive Data from a clients POST request in the pipeline. I tried several options i found online but nothing works...

Maybe someone has a useful thought on this.

Regards and thanks for everyone who helps.

Pipeline:

```
    p.addLast ("codec", new HttpServerCodec ());
    p.addLast("decoder", new HttpRequestDecoder());
    p.addLast("encoder", new HttpRequestEncoder());
    p.addLast("handler",new InboundHandlerA());
```

Handler:

```
private static class InboundHandlerA extends ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter{
     @Override
     public void channelActive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) {
         System.out.println("Connected!");
         ctx.fireChannelActive();
     } 

 public void channelRead (ChannelHandlerContext channelHandlerCtxt, Object msg) throws Exception   {

         System.out.println(msg);
     }
    }
```

Comment: What do you have at the moment? How does your current handler and pipeline look?

Comment: @Ferrybig i edited the post :) i want to do a switch case in channelRead for POST or GET

Comment: @Ferrybig I can specify my question: What method do i have to override (and how) in which handler to get POST Content

Answer (score 5):

Recieving HTTP requests using netty is simple, you can do this with the following pipeline:

```
// Provides support for http objects:
p.addLast("codec", new HttpServerCodec());
// Deals with fragmentation in http traffic: 
p.addLast("aggregator", new HttpObjectAggregator(Short.MAX_VALUE));
// Deals with optional compression of responses:
// p.addLast("aggregator", new HttpContentCompressor());
p.addLast("handler",new InboundHandlerA());
```

This can be used with a custom `SimpleChannelInboundHandler<FullHttpRequest>`:

```
public class InboundHandlerA extends SimpleChannelInboundHandler<FullHttpRequest> {

    @Override
    public void channelActive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) {
        super.channelActive(ctx);
        System.out.println("Connected!");
    } 

    // Please keep in mind that this method 
       will be renamed to messageReceived(ChannelHandlerContext, I) in 5.0.
    @Override
    public void channelRead0 (ChannelHandlerContext ctx, 
                              FullHttpRequest msg) throws Exception {
        // Check for invalid http data:
        if(msg.getDecoderResult() != DecoderResult.SUCCESS ) {
            ctx.close();
            return;
        }

        System.out.println("Recieved request!");
        System.out.println("HTTP Method: " + msg.getMethod());
        System.out.println("HTTP Version: " + msg.getProtocolVersion());
        System.out.println("URI: " + msg.getUri());
        System.out.println("Headers: " + msg.headers());
        System.out.println("Trailing headers: " + msg.trailingHeaders());

        ByteBuf data = msg.content();
        System.out.println("POST/PUT length: " + data.readableBytes());
        System.out.println("POST/PUT as string: ");
        System.out.println("-- DATA --");
        System.out.println(data.toString(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        System.out.println("-- DATA END --");

        // Send response back so the browser won't timeout
        ByteBuf responseBytes = ctx.alloc().buffer();
        responseBytes.writeBytes("Hello World".getBytes());

        FullHttpResponse response = new DefaultFullHttpResponse(
            HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1, HttpResponseStatus.OK, responseBytes);
        response.headers().set(HttpHeaders.Names.CONTENT_TYPE, 
                               "text/plain");
        response.headers().set(HttpHeaders.Names.CONTENT_LENGTH, 
                               response.content().readableBytes());

        response.headers().set(HttpHeaders.Names.CONNECTION, 
                               HttpHeaders.Values.KEEP_ALIVE);
        ctx.write(response);
    }
}
```

The code above is printing out all the details on a incoming message, including the post data. If you require only the post data, you can add a simple if-statement to filter on a POST response type

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I will figure out if it helps me now and write an answer after that :)

Comment: Many of the methods u use are marked as deprecated. I get the "Connected!" Message but no more. Maybe it's important to know for you that the Pipeline is created by a SocketChannel ch and final ChannelPipeline p = ch.pipeline();

Comment: i was able to use msg.getMethod() now. The problem seems to be this if-statement if(!msg.getDecoderResult()). i cant get it to work like that. it says: "The operator ! is undefined for the argument type(s) DecoderResult". i triet if(msg.getDecoderResult() !=null) with no resonable result...

Comment: Nice. That works better. Thank you! :) Another question even if you do data.toString() to print out the sent data. The consol line just says -- DATA --
CompositeByteBuf(ridx: 0, widx: 0, cap: 0, components=0)
-- DATA END -- any thoughts on the reason? Another thing i don't understand is, my Client sents a POST request. I can see this request in the INBOUND LOG. But its not displayed by the Handler.

Comment: If you are still having the problem of ntty not seeing the post request, check if netty sees the "http method" as POST, and that the length of the message is not 0. If your client send a complex format like a http form with files, you need to make some code that can read that format

Comment: I will check.  i wrote u an email to ur github mail adress. Feel free to answer. I can sent u my whole code if that helps... Thank you for your time!

Comment: This SimpleChannelInboundHandler is not getting called as of now (SpringBoot 2.5.0). Consider implementing WebFilter (WebFlux) or GlobalFilter (SpringCloud).